# How to calculate error function?

Tags: normal-distribution, error-function

I am learning the normal (Or Gaussiance) distribution, I see a result for error function, that is:

$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}dt=1$

I thought so much about it, who can give me an explanation for this result?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: This is a hard one and you need hard-to-guess tricks. One way is by writing a double integral and turning to polar coordinates...

Comment: It's a now-famous trick: you can compute $\left ( \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx \right )^2$ by computing $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-y^2} dx dy$ in polar coordinates. There you get the factor of "r" that you need to use integration by substitution.